# I am not able to See Pnp Powershell Documentation on Microsoft Site

Tags: powershell, office365, sharepoint-online

I am not able to browse Pnp Powershell documentation on Microsoft Site .

Please suggest new URL where I can refer the pnp powershell  cmdlet command documentation.

e.g.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps

will give you 404 error.

I was trying to see pnp Provisioning Template documentation.

Regards
Rajat Sahani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could view it on the internet archive.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033347/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Thank you. it is working. But why it is moved web.archive? what is latest URL for this documentation.

Comment: what is new Site for this documentation. How we will come know that this moved to archive.org. Can We download all this documentation offline

Comment: It’s not moved. The internet archive attempts to back up all the websites so they can be seen as they were at any point in time

Comment: Check these out https://github.com/pnp/powershell/tree/dev/documentation      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps